# Restriction for download an image in website

Tags: html, web-applications, web

How can i put an image in website that cannot be download by user.
or how can i protect my images from download in my web site?
i have tried to put in table as a background but still it is insecure. please suggest me a new idea.

Comment: If the user can see it, **it's already downloaded!**

Comment: ya but i dont want to allow to save on there computer.

Comment: That's simply out of your control. Your server releases the image data into the public and anyone can download it. Whether they save it on their computer or just temporarily look at it in their browser is a minor detail.

Comment: New idea: Don't think this way!  It's not productive.  There are too many good things to do without throwing up walls in people's way for dealing with an image you've already shown to them.  Once someone has seen an image it does, in some sense, belong to them and their memory.  If you don't want people to save something--in their heads or on their computer--don't show it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to have an image show in a browser that cannot be retrieved or captured by the end user.  That's just the way browsers work.  In the very least, someone can take a screenshot of what is on the screen and save that.

But, the very nature of the web and browsers means that any image that a browser can display can be captured by any user.

There are various obstacles that can be erected to make it slightly less convenient to capture an image such as make it a background image or putting a transparent gif over the top of it (both of which try to block the right-click save as options), but anyone who understands pretty much anything about how web pages and browsers work can bypass those obstacles in seconds.

You simply cannot have secure images display on the web.  Your choices are:

1. Put it on the web and don't worry about it.
2. Protect access to your site to only those whom you trust.
3. Put watermarks in the images so if/when people steal them, they are clearly watermarked with your copyright and identity and not as useful for prints or other things like that.
4. Don't display any image size on the web that would be a serious problem if it was stolen.
5. Clearly explain on your site that these are copyrighted images and are not to be borrowed or taken for other purposes and trust your user base to mostly follow that.

People who display images for selling purposes have to draw a balance between displaying a useful enough image to entice a sale, but not a useful enough image to attract too much image theft.  There is no other way around it.

Comment: Thanks for your responding.now i get some idea about this.
still i don't get u at point no 4 can u explain it?
& one more question..
Can images or photos be copyright ?

Comment: @Pulah - you don't way what you're trying to protect or why so it's hard for us to offer specifics.  For photographers displaying photos for sale, they may never put anything larger than 400x600 on the web because you can't make a high quality larger print from a 400x600 image.

Comment: Thank you so much. now i get your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to jfriend00's response - Another reason why you can't really have images that can't be downloaded is because of several plugins and tools people have - For Chrome you can press Ctrl+Shift+J and you can see all the resources a website has - you can also just save a whole website and download all the resources.

Without the above - You could perhaps do what some people do with the navs - You put an image before the link in css ':before' or ':after' and the image isn't save-able - but still - you can download ALL resources to the site via saving the site or the developer tools and so on.

The best suggestion is to do what Jfriend suggested as number 5 " Clearly explain on your site that these are copyrighted images and are not to be borrowed or taken for other purposes and trust your user base to mostly follow that." - Copyright < - Awesome.

Put it in your footer - make a link to a separate page and explicitly and articulately explain that your images are not to be reproduced or manipulated - Up to you what you want to do with your images.